# CoffeeScript updates not reflected on restart

Tags: node.js, express, coffeescript, foreman

I'm messing around with a fork of [foaas](http://foaas.com) (on [github](https://github.com/xenph/foaas)), a little service built with CoffeeScript and Node. I've got it running on an ec2 instance and, as a starting point, have just switched some of the hard-coded string values around in server.coffee.

After making my changes I run the server again with:

```
coffee server.coffee
```

The problem is that nothing changes! The strings I have swapped around still reflect their old values. Clearly I am missing some kind of build tool that's in place here. The dir tree looks like so:

```
├── lib
│   └── operations.coffee
├── LICENSE
├── package.json
├── Procfile
├── public
│   ├── googlead0e382f658e6d8e.html
│   └── index.html
├── README.md
└── server.coffee
```

From what I've gathered, I need a tool to read the Procfile in order to compile the coffeescript files into js and run them, all-at-once. That's quite an abstract thing to google and my attempts have proved fruitless. How do I get my changes reflected?

I haven't used Node much and haven't used CoffeeScript or Express at all but I have read their related documentation so *mostly* know what's happening in the code.

Comment: Use `grunt` to automate the compilation of Coffee files into JS, and watch changes to the coffee file. On every change, you can restart the server (or use Supervisor)

Comment: Do I need to compile the coffee file into JS? If i'm able to just run it with coffee server.coffee where does compilation come in?

Comment: Yes ofcourse you can do that too.

Comment: Supervisor running in the background has done the trick. Thanks!

Comment: I'm expanding the comment to an answer so that you can close this question properly as per StackOverflow's standard practices.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Expanded from the comment which solved the issue:

#### On every change, you can restart the server using `Supervisor`

---

As an additional step, for building your coffee files into js
you can use `grunt` to automate the compilation, and watch changes to the coffee file too.

Answer (score 1):

You'll need `foreman` to start your Procfile -- you can use `node-dev` to run your server (which automatically restarts upon changes).

```
npm install node-dev --save
```

And to avoid Grunt headaches, you could also specify compile watchers in your Procfile:

```
web: ./node_modules/node-dev/bin/node-dev server.coffee
coffee: ./node_modules/.bin/coffee --watch --compile --output ./ lib
```

And to run your Procfile: `foreman start -f Procfile`

See [here](http://coffeescript.org/#usage) for the coffee-script command line usage